# .htaccess file asks for password on parent directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I'm trying to use `.htaccess` to protect the CMS of a website I made. So there's the website's domain and then `www.example.com/cms` for the CMS. Of course, the CMS should be protected. I put both `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` in the cms folder. I linked the `.htaccess` file to `example.com/public_html/example/cms/.htpasswd`, but when I visit the `www.example.com` now, it also triggers the popup box for the password.

I can click it away and perfectly use the website, but of course I don't want users to be bothered by that pop up box all the time. The cms is not accessible and you can't click the pop up away and continue on to the website there. So actually, it's all working fine except for the pop op showing up 'to early'.

I must be making a stupid mistake... anyone knows what it is?

EDIT - Here's the .htaccess file's contents (with the actual links replaced by 'example.com')

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "CMS | Restricted"  
AuthUserFile /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/website/cms/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess here?

Comment: @Joris508 edit and add that to your question, rather than a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added it to the question!

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in the root of the site?

Comment: @w3d no, it's in the root of the folder that I want to be restricted.

Comment: Yes, but do you have _another_ .htaccess file in the document root of your site? Any directives in your server config?

Comment: I placed it in there first, but now I've moved it. Double checked if it is gone and yes, it is. No directives in the server config that I have put in there... but I don't know a lot about server config... it's my school's server.

Comment: Does you main website www.example.com load any element from www.example.com/cms  ?

Comment: Oh my... that's probably it. I think it loads in some images that are inside the CMS folder, because they're uploaded through a php file in the CMS into a folder next to that PHP file. I'm such an idiot. I'll check out if that's it when I'm back from work. I'll let you guys know, but I'm sure that is it.